# Flash player not working in firefox with 14.04 LTS on facebook

Tags: flash

Fresh install of 14.04 and using Firefox. Cannot play games on Face book - will not download - says I need to install at least version 10. to continue.
have also installed vlc. I am a newb

Comment: Please open a terminal window (CTRL+ALT+T), type `dpkg -l | grep flash` and [edit] your question to show us the output.

Comment: dpkg: error: unknown option -1

Comment: It's a lowercase letter L, not the number one!

Comment: ii  flashplugin-installer                                 11.2.202.554ubuntu0.14.04.1                         i386         Adobe Flash Player plugin installer

Answer (score 1):

Please open a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-installer
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
```

After restarting Firefox, you will be able to use Flash 19 that way.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash

Comment: Run `sudo add-apt-repository multiverse` first, please.

Comment: run multiverse before purge? or before install?

Comment: same result as before

Comment: What Ubuntu version do you use? My package only exists starting from 15.10... :-/

Comment: I have 14.04 lts

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem, and have you tried this:

```
 sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree
```

and then this:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: sudo apt-get install flasplayer-nonfree
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package flasplayer-nonfree

Comment: divemaster91: flasHplayer-nonfree

Comment: I 'm sorry for my bad keystrokes but get the same results... E: Unable to locate package flashplayer-nonfree

Comment: @divemaster91 flash**plugin**-nonfree

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED !!!
I had to to load chromium and pepperflash with the adobe flash-plugin installed as well.
also could not use face book messenger web app, had to access thru browser for everything to work.